# Regex to detect all numbers in decimal form where decimal number is not fixed

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am editing a HTML file in notepad++ which contains the numbers like

```
x
x.x
x.x.x
x.x.x.x
x.x.x.x.x
```

the number of decimals may be zero or more.

where x is any number for ex:

```
1 
or 
1.2
or
3.4.1
or 
401.23.5
```

I want to create a regex to find all such instances in the file please help

I have tried the following regex

```
For 5 Decimals [0-9]{1,4}\.[0-9]{1,4}\.[0-9]{1,4}\.[0-9]{1,4}\.[0-9]{1,4}\.[0-9]{1,4}
For 4 Decimals [0-9]{1,4}\.[0-9]{1,4}\.[0-9]{1,4}\.[0-9]{1,4}\.[0-9]{1,4}
For 3 Decimals [0-9]{1,4}\.[0-9]{1,4}\.[0-9]{1,4}\.[0-9]{1,4}
For 2 Decimals [0-9]{1,4}\.[0-9]{1,4}\.[0-9]{1,4}
For 1 Decimal  [0-9]{1,4}\.[0-9]{1,4}
```

I have to use this regex individually I want to create a regex that will universally detect all the occurrences of any number of decimals

Comment: So, you just did not know that you can use a grouping construct and apply a quantifier to the whole group. I'd use `\b\d{1,4}(?:\.\d{1,4})*\b`, or - if you need to limit to 5 "decimals" - `\b(?<!\.)\d{1,4}(?:\.\d{1,4}){0,4}(?!\.)\b`. To match one or more, you may just use `+`.

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew can you please explain or suggest some site where I can learn about the grouping construct

Comment: See https://regexone.com/. It can be enough. More [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). And to see how quantifiers work - http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#basics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
\d+(\.\d+)*
```

Explanation:

- `\d+` : matches one or more digits
- `\.\d+`: matches a literal dot and more than one digits
- `(__)*` : matches the regex in capture group zero or more times

See [DEMO](https://www.regex101.com/r/5IZPLD/1)

Comment: It works thanks. Can you please explain the given regex and please in layman terms

Comment: @KaranParikh added explanation, ask if something is not clear :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what language are you using but in java we have:

```
String number="1.5";
String num  = "[0-9.]+";
boolean torf = number.matches(num);
```

if the the string matched returns true otherwise returns false.

Comment: This will match `...........` or `123456789` or `..11...2....3...4567.` that is not wanted.